# Finding eigenfunction(s)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

I am stuck in a part of a proof perhaps somebody can help me.

I've got the following eigenvalue problem:

$$u'' + \lambda u = 0 \quad 0 <x < L$$
With boundary conditions: 
$$ -u'(0) + \sigma_1 u(0) = 0, \quad u'(L) + \sigma_2 u(L) = 0$$
Where both $ \sigma_1$ and $ \sigma_2$ are constants.

By writing $\lambda = k^2$, for real $k$, the general solution is :
$$u(x) = A \cos kx + B \sin kx$$
and imposing the boundary conditions: 
$u(0) = A$, $u(L) =A \cos kL + B \sin kL$, $u'(x)= -kA \sin kx +kB \cos kx$

Now substituting the given boundary values: 
$u'(0) = kB$, and $u'(L) = -kA \sin  kL +kB  \cos kL$

Which gives:

$$-kB + \sigma_1A = 0 $$
$$-kA \sin  kL +kB  \cos kL + \sigma_2(A \cos kL + B \sin kL)=0$$

The last equation can be re-arranged to:
$$(-kA+\sigma_2B) \sin KL + (kB + \sigma_2A)\cos kL = 0 $$
Giving: 
$$\frac{(-kA+\sigma_2B)}{(kB + \sigma_2A)}\tan kL = -1$$
Now solving for $\tan kL$ gives:

$$\tan kL = -\frac {(kB + \sigma_2A)}{(-kA+\sigma_2B)}$$

By using the first BC we obtain:

$$\tan kL =\frac {(\sigma_1 + \sigma_2)k}{(k^2-\sigma_1 \sigma_2)}$$

But how do I get to the corresponding eigen function:

$$u_n(x) = u(x;k_n) \quad u(x;k) = K(k) \sin(kx + θ(k))$$
where:

$$\tan(θ(k))= \frac {k}{\sigma_1}$$

For some undetermined normalisation constant $K(k)$

Comment: What is exactly your problem: determination of the constants?

Comment: My problem is to get to the eigenfunction(s). I determined the eigenvalues, but can't see how I get to the corresponding eigenfunction

Comment: Have not you found the eigenfunctions already in the third formula? It remains only to determine the constants $A$ and $B$, does not it?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The constant A must be zero.. But how ?

Comment: It is not zero!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:*

Recall that:
$$
A\cos x + B\sin x= K\sin(x+\phi)
$$
with
$$
K=\sqrt{A^2+B^2},\quad \phi=\arctan\frac AB.
$$

Comment: Can we just say: $K(k) =\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ ? Don't we have extra conditions?

Comment: @JoeGoldiamond I have given a general formula connecting two representations of sine function. In your case $K$ is an arbitrary number (particularly independent of $k$), which you can immediately recognize recalling that the differential operator is linear. Only the phase matters. And you have already found it (cf. your 4th formula).

Comment: So could we say that the eigenfunction is only depending on $\sigma_1$? but the eigen values are depending on both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$?